# Efficiently convert gmpy2.mpz to numpy boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, gmpy

I try to convert from gmpy2.mpz to a numpy boolean array, but can't quite get it right. (gmpy2: https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io)

```
import gmpy2
import numpy as np

x = gmpy2.mpz(int('1'*1000,2))

print("wrong conversion 1")
y = np.fromstring(gmpy2.to_binary(x), dtype=bool) # this is wrong
print(np.sum(y)) # this returns 127 instead of 1000

print("wrong conversion 2")
y = np.fromstring(gmpy2.to_binary(x), dtype=np.uint8)
print(y) # array([  1,   1, 255 ... 255], dtype=uint8)
y_bool = np.unpackbits(y)
slow_popcount = np.sum(y_bool, dtype=int)
print(slow_popcount) # 1002. should be 1000

print("Fudging an answer. This is wrong as well.")
y = np.fromstring(gmpy2.to_binary(x)[2:], dtype=np.uint8)
# is that slicing [2:] a slow operation?
y_bool = np.unpackbits(y)
print np.sum(y_bool, dtype=int) # 1000
```

More tests:

```
np.fromstring(gmpy2.to_binary(gmpy2.mpz(int('1'*64,2))), dtype=np.uint8)
# array([  1,   1, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
np.fromstring(gmpy2.to_binary(gmpy2.mpz(int('1'*65,2))), dtype=np.uint8)
# array([  1,   1, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   1], dtype=uint8
np.fromstring(gmpy2.to_binary(gmpy2.mpz(int('1'*66,2))), dtype=np.uint8)
# array([  1,   1, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   3], dtype=uint8)
np.fromstring(gmpy2.to_binary(gmpy2.mpz(int('1'*1024,2))), dtype=np.uint8)
# array([  1,   1, 255 ... 255], dtype=uint8)
```

By the way, I actually want to quickly get a list, array, or numpy array of indices of all set bit of a gmpy2.mpz. The actual 4,777,000 gmpy2.mpz that I try to convert each has 760,000 bits with about 2,000 bits of 1. The gmp library on the computer was compiled with intel icc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options. The function `gmpy2.bit_scan1(x, n)` will return the index of the first bit that is set that has an index >= n.

```
>>> x = gmpy2.mpz(123456)
>>> bin(x)
'0b11110001001000000'
>>> n = 0
>>> while True:
...     n = gmpy2.bit_scan1(x, n)
...     if n is None:
...         break
...     print(n)
...     n = n + 1
... 
6
9
13
14
15
16
```

The `gmpy2` also supports an integer type called `xmpz`. It is an experimental version of the `mpz` type. The primary difference is that `xmpz` type is mutable - in-place operations will directly modify the value without creating a copy. This makes the `xmpz` type very useful for bit manipulations. For example, you can extract and modify bit positions using slice notation.

The `xmpz` type also supports methods called `iter_set`, `iter_clear`, and `iter_bits`.

```
>>> x_str='1'*8+'01'
>>> x_int=gmpy2.xmpz(x_str, 2)
>>> list(x_int.iter_set())
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(x_int.iter_clear())
[1]
>>> list(x_int.iter_bits())
[True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

I originally wrote the `xmpz` type to evaluate any performance improvements for optimizing in-place operations. Bit manipulation saw the greatest benefits. Here is a short and fast implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
def sieve(limit=1000000):
    '''Returns a generator that yields the prime numbers up to limit.'''

    sieve_limit = gmpy2.isqrt(limit) + 1
    limit += 1
    # Mark bit positions 0 and 1 as not prime.
    bitmap = gmpy2.xmpz(3)
    # Process 2 separately. This allows us to use p+p for the step size
    # when sieving the remaining primes.
    bitmap[4 : limit : 2] = -1
    # Sieve the remaining primes.
    for p in bitmap.iter_clear(3, sieve_limit):
        bitmap[p*p : limit : p+p] = -1
    return bitmap.iter_clear(2, limit)
```

Comment: I used iter_set in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it is slow.

```
import gmpy2
import numpy as np
x_str = '1'*8+'01'
print(x_str)
x_int = int(x_str,2)
x_mpz = gmpy2.mpz(x_int)
x_01 = bin(int(x_mpz))[2:] # get rid of '0b'
x_bin = x_01.replace('1','\x01').replace('0','\x00')
x_np_bool = np.fromstring(x_bin, dtype = bool)
x_1_index = np.where(x_np_bool)[0]
print(x_1_index)
```